# Python dictionary is somehow updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've tried my best to figure this out, but I can't for the life of me. I have a dictionary with many different values in it, including another dictionary. Before setting the values for the dictionary within the dictionary, I try to set the values equal to a "blank" dictionary such that in subsequent steps I can update it.

The short story is: I have two lines that somehow are changing a dictionary that I wouldn't expect. Given some dicts:
`blankresiduedict = {stuff:[stuff], stuff:[stuff]}; blankidentifiers = {stuff:stuff, stuff:stuff}`

the lines

```
self.pdb_chain_dict['1MH9_B'] = (blankresiduedict.copy(),blankidentifiers.copy())
self.pdb_chain_dict['1MH9_B'][0][(stuff)][0] = residuedict[('A','D','41')]
```

are somehow changing the values of blankresiduedict to be equal to residuedict.

#### Any idea how this is happening? There is literally no other reference to blankresiduedict in that section of code, and when I look at the output, blankresiduedict starts out accurate and then with each loop keeps changing value to equal whatever residuedict was for that loop.

---

---

## (Below is a more detailed description)

This is a small part of a very large project, so some of this may really be hard to represent in a compact form. I'll do my best to eliminate the unnecessary stuff. This is a method within a class that I am trying to use to update the dictionary for the class instance.

```
blankresiduedict = {}
blankidentifiers = {}
self.allowmultiples = True
self.ancestorline = [
    '1MH9', 
    'A', 'D', '41',
    'A', 'D', '43',
    'A', 'T', '130', 
    #etc...
]
self.no_key_residues = 6
self.pdb_chain_dict = {
    '1MH9_B': (
        {
            ('A','D','41'): [('B','D','41')],
            ('A','D','43'): [('B','D','43')], 
            ('A','T','130'): [('B','T','130')]
        }, 
        #{identifiers dictionary}
    ), 
    '1MH9_C': (
        #{etc},{etc}
    ), 
    # etc...
}


for i in range(1, (3*self.no_key_residues)+1, 3): # Using this loop structure allows a variable number of key residues to be given
    if not self.allowmultiples:
        raise Exception("Do some stuff here")
    else:
        blankresiduedict[(self.ancestorline[i],self.ancestorline[i+1],self.ancestorline[i+2])] = [('-','-','-')] 
blankidentifiers = {'EC Num':'-','Sprot':'-','Class':'-','Keywords':'-','Title':'-','SeqRepr':'-'}

### Begin some loop structure, where for every loop, the following is basically happening
residuedict = {
    ('A','D','41'): ('B','D','10'), 
    ('A','D','43'): ('B','D','12')
} #in actuality this value would change for every loop, but just showing what a typical loop would look like
self.pdb_chain_dict['1MH9_B'] = (blankresiduedict.copy(),blankidentifiers.copy())
self.pdb_chain_dict['1MH9_B'][0][('A','D','41')][0] = residuedict[('A','D','41')]
```

What should happen here is that the value in the pdb_chain_dict is set to the the tuple of two blank dictionaries ({residuedict},{identifiers}) I'm mostly leaving the identifier dictionary alone in this example because it has the exact same problem. However, what I'm finding is that the blankresiduedict is actually changing. And, after doing a lot of testing, the line where it is changing is `self.pdb_chain_dict['1MH9_B'][0][('A,'D','41')][0] = residuedict[('A','D','41')]`.

This makes no sense to me...blankresiduedict is not even involved, yet somehow it's value is being changed in that step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because a copy of a dictionary is not a deep copy, and your dict values are lists, which are mutable. Here's a minimal example that reproduces your issue:

```
d1 = {"foo": [1, 2, 3]}
d2 = d1.copy()
# Add a new element to d2 to show that the copy worked
d2["bar"] = []

# The two dicts are different.
print d1
print d2

# However, the list wasn't copied 
# it's the same object that shows up in 2 different dicts
print d1["foo"] is d2["foo"]

# So that's what happens in your code: you're mutating the list.
d1["foo"].append(5)
print d2["foo"]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that. That's a good illustration of how the copy is not "deep", but how can I generate a genuine copy while retaining the list? One approach I just tried out was "recreating" the blank dictionaries for each loop so that they can effectively not be rewritten. However, this does not feel like a very "Pythonic" way of handling it.

Comment: The problem is not the dict itself, it's the list that it contains. I'd suggest recreating the list instead of mutating it, e.g. `d2["foo"] = [1, 2, 3, 5]` in my example, or rebuilding `self.pdb_chain_dict['1MH9_B'][0][('A,'D','41')]` in yours. Alternately, the `deepcopy` module will, as the name implies, make deep copies, but I find its use distasteful.

Comment: I'd use `copy.deepcopy` (or a language where everything is mutable).

Comment: @sweeneyrod: Note that mutability, in this case, is the reason why there is a problem in the first place ;)

Comment: @MaxNoel Yeah, I meant immutable!